# I want to save the results as variables instead of printing them in an array

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am using the following code that gets what is between `<p>` and `</p>`. Instead of displaying the result in an array how can I save every paragraph in a new variable ?
Thank you!

Comment: why do you want it? such question just makes no sense.

Comment: Hi there. My purpose is to save in variables all the paragraphs of a page. So i would be able to add some PHP code and use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that

```
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    doSomething with $match[1];
}
```

should do the trick. `$matches` should contain a list of each match, where a match consist of the whole string matched and then the groups. Since there is only one group in each match that you are interested, `$match[1]` should give you the content of the paragraph, `$match[0]` the whole paragraph with the `<p>` tags on it.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. I tried to echo it and it prints several times (depends on how many <p></p> are in the site) ...

Comment: It prints the same paragraph multiple times, one time for each paragraph? So `<p>A</p><p>B</p><p>C</p>` would result in `AAA`? Then you might try `foreach ($matches[0] as $paragraph) echo $paragraph;`.